# Typescript interface generics

Tags: typescript, generics

Could someone help me understand what `T = {}` means in the following typescript interface? I cannot find docs indicating such usage. How is it different from just `T`?

```
interface CustomProps<T = {}> {
      itemId: string;
      id: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called generic parameter defaults and were introduced in TypeScript 2.3. You can find the documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults).

For your example, it means that if no type parameter is specified, it will default to `{}`, which is commonly referred to as the *empty object type*.